# What is the difference between Referenda and Democracy pallets?

Tags: pallet, frame, governance

Both [Democracy](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/democracy) and [Referenda](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/referenda) pallets are used for purposes of on-chain governance.

However, only Democracy is used on Polkadot and Kusama runtimes. What is the difference between these two pallets?

Comment: It is explained here in this [blog post](https://polkadot.network/blog/gov2-polkadots-next-generation-of-decentralised-governance/), it is currently not yet deployed but is coming up [on Kusama](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5205).